# laravel relation hasMany accessor count()

Tags: mysql, laravel-5, eloquent, relational-database

I've got these models

Machine:

```
->id
->...
```

Server

```
->id
->machine_id
->is_suspended
```

Relations from Machine model:

```
public function servers()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Server');
}

//with suspended servers
public function getFreePortsAmountAllAttribute()
{
    return $this->servers->count();
}

//without suspended servers
public function getFreePortsAmountAttribute()
{
    return $this->servers->where('servers.is_suspended', false)->count();
}
```

Using this relations, when I create 2 servers (1 suspended, 1 not suspended) and calling:

```
dd(Machine::find(1)->free_ports_amount);
```

Returns 0, so for some reason the accessor doesn't work. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

you are calling the "servers" accessor not the query builder "servers()", try these changes:

```
//with suspended servers
public function getFreePortsAmountAllAttribute()
{
    return $this->servers()->count();
}

//without suspended servers
public function getFreePortsAmountAttribute()
{
   return $this->servers()->where('is_suspended', false)->count();
}
```